# In magento 2, How to use inbuild PHPunit testing tool for jenkins

Tags: magento2, phpunit

I am working on magento 2 project. I am using Jenkins as continuous integration tool. How can I use Jenkins for PHP unit testing for Magento 2. I know Magento 2 has inbuilt tool for unit testing. How can I use this inbuilt testing tool with jerkins.

Comment: this depends on if you just want to execute unit tests (with no dependencies on the magento framework) or want to utilize the magento testing frameworks. Setting up a ci env for just running unit tests without utilizing the magento framework is quite easy while utilizing the magento testing frameworks adds a lot of complexity, depending on the type of tests you want to execute

Comment: @DavidVerholen I want to use magento unit testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use the magento testing frameworks you need the magento codebase in your build. So if not in your repository, the first step would be to deploy magento

in the `dev/tests/unit` directory you find a `phpunit.xml.dist` which is preconfigured to execute the Magento tests.

you need a copy of this file in your repository, but without the `.dist` at the end and adjust it so that phpunit will execute your own tests.

so the next step would be to ensure you have the adjusted file at `dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml`

next, you can execute phpunit from the test directory like this (example shell script):

```
cd dev/tests/unit && ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml
```

Comment: Do you need to have run `magento setup:install` or is `composer install` enough?